# Object cannot be nil error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I am getting an error when I try to add a new object to `dataArray`.  This is how I define `dataArray`.

```
-(NSMutableArray *)dataArray{
    if (!_dataArray){   
        _dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                      [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [NSMutableArray array],
                       [NSMutableArray array],
                       [NSMutableArray array],
                       nil],
                      [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [NSMutableArray array],
                       [NSMutableArray array],
                       [NSMutableArray array],
                       nil], 
                      nil];
    }
    return _dataArray;
}
```

This is where I attempt to add an object to `dataArray`:

```
[[[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0] addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[attributeDict objectForKey:@"material"], [attributeDict objectForKey:@"tool"]]];
[[[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:1] addObject:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"level"]];
[[[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:2] addObject:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"probability"]];
```

Here is the error I am getting:  `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'`

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: You need to provide information about `attributeDict`. My guess is that one of `[attributeDict objectForKey:]` call is returning nil?

Comment: This adding 3 objects, one at a time.  Which statement is causing the error?  What does [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:0] return?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it.  I misspelled a variable name.

Answer (score 4):

Your argument to `addObject:` is likely `nil`.

Test it:

```
assert(attributeDict);
assert([attributeDict objectForKey:@"level"]);
assert([attributeDict objectForKey:@"probability"]);
```

Comment: even when I set addObject to a string, it gives me the same error

Comment: @blake305: You mean you're passing a constant string to *every* occurrence of `addObject:` and still getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

One of the values you're trying to insert is coming back `nil`, which means `attributeDict` does not contain either a "level" or "probability" key. The string should not be `nil` even if it's provided with nil arguments, they just display as `(nil)`.

Comment: even when I set addObject to a string, it gives me the same error

Comment: If that is the case, the string must be getting deallocated before it's trying to print it out. I doubt that's what's happening.