# How to fix arrayWithObject cannot be nil warning?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsarray, static-analysis, clang-static-analyzer

When running analyze in Xcode I get this warning:

> Argument to 'NSArray' method 'arrayWithObject:' cannot be nil

The line of code that it is happening on for me:

```
if (indexPath) {
    indexPath = [self differentPath:indexPath];
}
NSArray *exampleArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
```

Which is inside a `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate method.

How do I fix this warning?

Comment: what line of code is generating this warning?

Comment: Close your eyes.  Or you could tell us what's on the line that's being flagged.

Comment: I updated the question with the line of code.

Comment: Uh, that's not the line of code that's raising the error.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort

Comment: @ColdLogic Everything in google for this warning points to non relevant links. Do you have an example of a relevant link?

Comment: @SteveMoser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797282/object-cannot-be-nil-error

Comment: @SteveMoser https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSArray/arrayWithObjects:

Comment: @ColdLogic Both links refer to issues at runtime not compile/static analysis time.

Comment: @SteveMoser the answer is the same for either instances.

Comment: (You notice that the error message said "Argument to 'NSArray' method 'arrayWithObjects:' cannot be nil", yet you posted a statement that uses `arrayWithObject`, a different method.  In other words, you failed to observe the statement number in the message and find that statement number in your code, wasting our time in the process.  Not the way to win friends and influence people around here.)

Comment: @HotLicks Sorry, I apologize. I see the mistake and it does influence the question. Thank you for pointing it out. I wish I could have copied and pasted the warning from my client's computer but I can't login to SO from my client's computer thus missing a character when transcribing from the computer to my phone.

Comment: @ColdLogic I would argue that the answer isn't necessarily the same. For example if this code is in a library or framework you might want to assert that parameters entering certain methods are non nil and thus you would use an 'if' statement. Otherwise if this is app code that you know will never pass in a nil parameter then you might want to figure out the warning or tell the compiler to ignore it if you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is pretty clearly pointing to the fix: make sure the object cannot be nil. There are two different easy ways to fix this.

First you could make sure you are setting your pointer to a valid object within the same method as the arraryWithObject: call.

Or you could you could wrap your arraryWithObject: call in an if statement that checks that your object isn't nil.